# want to run multiple SQL script file in one go with in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have to run multiple SQL script file in one go.

Like every time i have to write command in SQLPLUS

```
SQL>@d:\a.txt 
SQL>@d:\a2.txt
SQL>@d:\a3.txt
SQL>@d:\a4.txt
```

is there any way put all file in one folder & run all script file in one go without missing any single file like  `@d:\final.txt` or `@d\final.bat`

Comment: have you tried windows batch file ? (open notepad, write the commands in sequence line by line) and then save the file as FileName.bat (make sure you have selected All Files option from bottom of the save dialogue. Running the batch file by double click shall do the trick. Or you may need a little advanced batch commands inside that bat file

Answer (score 14):

There is no single SQL*Plus command to do that, but you can create a single script that calls all the others:

Put the following into a batch file

```
@echo off
echo.>"%~dp0all.sql"
for %%i in ("%~dp0"*.sql) do echo @"%%~fi" >> "%~dp0all.sql"
```

When you run that batch file it will create a new script named `all.sql` in the same directory where the batch file is located. It will look for all files with the extension `.sql` in the same directory where the batch file is located.

You can then run all scripts by using `sqlplus user/pwd @all.sql` (or extend the batch file to call `sqlplus` after creating the `all.sql` script)

Comment: @rahuljain: sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: i ran the batch file. all.sql file is created fine. i open this file this file have code
@"D:\test_SQL\Patch03.01.486.txt"
 @"D:\test_SQL\Patch03.01.487.txt" 
@"D:\test_SQL\Patch03.01.488.txt"

if i run file like @all.sql is this will working fine?
i have to run this all txt files in prod

Comment: This helps me a lot, great answer

Comment: Fun fact: if you first create `all.sql` and then put all *.sql files in it, you'll end up having `all.sql` pointing to `all.sql`) Therefore you better delete that reference to avoid eternal circular execution

Answer (score 7):

If you're using gnu linux, you could use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD@DOMAIN < <(cat a.txt a2.txt a3.txt a4.txt) 
# ... or a for loop on input files, inside the process substitution
```

Alternatively, you can create a `.pdc` file and list your sql scripts:

```
-- pdc file
@a.txt;
@a2.txt;
@a3.txt;
@a4.txt;
```

and call sql plus:

```
sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD@DOMAIN < my_scripts.pdc
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. However i haven many files numbered file1.sql, file2.sql .. fileN.sql and they are listed in all.sql file like
all.sql
--@file1.sql
--@file2.sql
--...
--@fileN.sql

The problem is the files are not executed in the order in which they are listed.
How can i force it to use the order of the files like listed in the all.sql file ?

Thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 3):

Some tricks and command can help you to generate master.sql file and you can run from that location.

```
 c:\direcotory_location\dir *.sql /-t /b >master.sql
```

Go to the parent directory open master.sql open using notepad++ 
 remove master.sql line and use regular expression to replace

```
   \n  with \n @
```

go to cmd
From cmd

```
    C:\root_directory\sqlplus user/password @master.sql
```

I find this process very convenient if i have 30 to 40 scripts placed in a single directory.

Answer (score 3):

Use `*.PDC` extension file like this

**install.pdc**  file content

```
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode

prompt started!

prompt 1.executing script 1
@@install/01.script_1.sql

prompt 2.executing script 2
@@install/02.script_2.sql

prompt 3.executing script 3
@@install/03.script_3.sql

prompt finished!
```

where `@@install/` points in which directory is the SQL script located

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth the time to write a shell script that runs multiple files.

```
#!/bin/ksh
sqlplus user/password@instance <<EOF
@a.txt
@a1.txt
exit
EOF
```

For more on the syntax, look into [Here Document](https://superuser.com/questions/1003760/what-does-eof-do)

Answer (score 1):

here is similar solution but you do not have to iterate and to have special formated an sql file names. You compose an one sql file and run it once.

```
cat table_animal.sql > /tmp/temp.sql
cat table_horse.sql >> /tmp/temp.sql
cat table_fish.sql >> /tmp/temp.sql
sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD@DOMAIN @/tmp/temp.sql
```

Comment: Similarly, if you want to concatenate all of the SQL files in a directory, you can use `cat *.sql > temp.sql`.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows try 
copy /b *.sql +x final.sql

sqlplus user/password @final.sql

Answer (score -2):

Special Thanks to **Joseph Torre**

```
sqlplus login/password@server @filename
```

[reference link](https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-to-run-multiple-query-in-sequences-in-sql-plus-071513)

Comment: This handles just a single sql file for which the topic owner already had a solution.