# SQL*Plus order of sequential execution of many sql files listed in a script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to execute many SQL files sequentially named like file1.sql, file2.sql .. fileN.sql. I listed them in a file called all.sql. like below:

```
@file1.sql    
@file2.sql  
@file3.sql
```

and then I executed the sqlplus command
like:

```
sqlplus username/password@domain @all.sql
```

the problem is: The files where executed but not in the order in which they are listed in all.sql file.

So the question is: how can I force sqlplus to execute the files in the order in which they appear in the all.sql file?

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I have never seen the behaviour in almost 30 years of using SQL\*Plus and I can't see how it would even be possible.

Comment: Which database version are you using?

Comment: @user75ponic I am using Oracle11.2 Express Edition

Comment: @William Robertson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680829/want-to-run-multiple-sql-script-file-in-one-go-with-in-sqlplus

Comment: That is a different question, about dynamically executing all .sql files in a directory. But in this case, you have written a script called `all.sql` which you say is executing its contents in the wrong order. I have never seen any script in any language do that, ever.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a `plsql`command as yet. Maybe it's a script that spawns a separate SQL*Plus session for each given file?

If you use SQL*Plus to run your all.sql file, you should get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Plus executes the commands in order just as they appear in the file. Just imagine what would happen otherwise, as the Oracle database itself is build with .sql files (in $ORACLE_HOME/rdmbs/admin/). If the order of the creation scripts would be non-deterministic, chaos would be certain.

Can you show us a minimal example where the order is not kept (with probably mini scripts that print only a line to the output?