# How to add SET SCAN OFF in batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

So I made a batch script to RUN an SQL file. But this SQL doesn't have a SET SCAN OFF in it.

Any idea please how can i add "SET SCAN OFF" in my batch script before running the SQL File ?

````
set password=%1
set database=%2
set sqlfile=%3
set logfile=%4

IF "%~1"=="" GOTO endpoint
IF "%~2"=="" GOTO endpoint
IF "%~3"=="" GOTO endpoint
IF "%~4"=="" GOTO endpoint
echo exit | sqlplus SYSADM/%password%@%database% @C:\Users\%sqlfile% >%logfile%
GOTO :eof

:endpoint
echo "Vérifiez vos parametres!"```
````

Comment: One option is to use a [User Profile script](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch2.htm#i1132910) - just create a file named "login.sql" in the working directory and put `SET SCAN OFF` in it to make it the default behavior for any script run from that directory.

Comment: You can also create a "master script" which runs `SET SCAN OFF` and then calls your `@script.sql` - see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680829/want-to-run-multiple-sql-script-file-in-one-go-with-in-sqlplus)

Comment: Lines `1` through `4` of your provided code, appear to serve little purpose, _(they're effectively creating variables to hold variables you already have)_. Lines `6` through `8` also have no useful purpose, more especially in the position you've chosen to place them within your script. You could have probably performed the same task using just this line: `@If Not "%~4" == "" (Echo exit | sqlplus SYSADM/%1@%2 @C:\Users\%3 >%4) Else Echo Vérifiez vos parametres!& timeout 3 >NUL`.